# Xamarin.Android API level 19 bug

Tags: android, api, sdk, xamarin

I have downloaded Xamarin Studio and am trying to use the MapsAndLocationDemo3 sample with the MapWithOverlaysActivity project.

I am getting the following error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA0000: Could not determine $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for API level '19.' (XA0000) (SimpleMapDemo)

I have been told that this is a bug in Xamarin.Android when API level 19 is installed in the Android SDK. It's fixed in 4.10.2.

May I have a download link to download this version?

Answer (score 1):

I think in one Xamarin forum, it is mentioned that if you change the entry in .csproj file from "True" to False it would solve the problem. I got the same error and was redirected to the Xamarin forum and I tried the trick.

Open your .csproj in any text editor (Notepad++), search for AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk and set the flag value as false.

I believe it is because of latest Android SDK or something, but at least its a working workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is the download link of Xamarin.Android 4.10.2:
    http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.10.02005_signed.msi